# Unclear compile error for mpd with ffmpeg on Mac arm64 architecture (M1)

Tags: c++, macos, ffmpeg, arm64, mpd

I tried to compile (and install) mpd via brew with
`brew reinstall --build-from-source mpd` but ffmpeg seems to have some error with the arm64 architecture as the error states:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "av_free(void*)", referenced from:
      AvioStream::~AvioStream() in libdecoder_plugins.a(FfmpegIo.cxx.o)
  "av_malloc(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      AvioStream::Open() in libdecoder_plugins.a(FfmpegIo.cxx.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I reinstalled ffmpeg (and even it build from source) to make sure it built the arm64 version. Can anyone help me out, about what could be problem?

Comment: [You should check this](https://ffmpeg.org/platform.html) to see if anything there affects you. Beyond that, your linker error indicates that in your link you [are missing a required file or library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/631266). AFAICT it might be "libav", but I am unfamiliar with ffmpeg.

Comment: Unfortunatly I could not solve the problems with your advice, but thanks a lot for the references!

Answer (score 0):

With an update to 0.28.1 the dependency I could successfully compile it. According to the change logs of the succeeding version 0.29 a build bug has been fixed for macOS:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MusicPlayerDaemon/MPD/v0.23.9/NEWS

I assume this has been fixed with the commit https://github.com/MusicPlayerDaemon/MPD/commit/59792cb0b801854ee41be72d33db9542735df754 and the related update of the ffmpeg dependency to version 5.1.